# Different between two date times (With running example) - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the difference in minutes between this two date times but I keep getting -21 minutes. I don't understand what is wrong. Any help please?

I believe it's only couting the minutes of the hour. What I actually want is the minutes even between the days. It should be something like 21600 (15 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes)

```js
let endDate = new Date("2019-01-17T20:30");
let beginDate = new Date();

console.log("EndDate: " + endDate, "// Begin Date: " + beginDate);

var diffMs = (endDate - beginDate);
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
console.log("Minutes: " + diffMins);
```

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your calculation of `diffMins`?

Comment: The difference between timestamps is calculated in miliseconds, so if you need to translate those to minutes, simply divide by 60000 (6e4). Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1000 to get seconds and then by 60 to get minutes.

```js
let endDate = new Date("2019-01-17T20:30");
let beginDate = new Date();

console.log( Math.round((endDate - beginDate) / 1000 / 60) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give you the answer. To check if the calculation is right, you can use this online calculator: [Calculate duration between two dates](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=17&m1=1&y1=2019&d2=2&m2=1&y2=2020&h1=20&i1=30&s1=0&h2=22&i2=0&s2=39)

```
var startTime = new Date("2019-01-17T20:30"); 
var endTime = new Date(); // today's date
var difference = Math.abs(endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()); // This will give difference in milliseconds
var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calculating the difference incorrectly.

Try this code:

```js
let endDate = new Date("2019-01-17T20:30");
let beginDate = new Date();
console.log("EndDate: " + endDate, "// Begin Date: " + beginDate);

var diffMs = (endDate - beginDate);
var diffMins = Math.floor(Math.abs(diffMs / 60000)); // minutes
console.log("Minutes: " + diffMins);
```

We divide the milliseconds by 1000 to make it seconds and then by 60 to make it minutes, thus 60000.